# Updating based on two different loss functions, but with a different optimizer learning rate after each one (pytorch)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a set up as follows, where I have an outer for loop iterating over epochs, and an inner for loop iterating over batches.

In the inner for loop, over batches, I'm usin a cross entropy loss, and using an Adam optimizer with a certain learning rate.

After the inner for loop (after all batches are evaluated), I'm then calculating another loss function based off of the output (a custom loss function), and optimizing.

However, I notice that when I define a different optimizer with a different learning rate, it doesn't seem to be training. When I keep the same optimizer, it seems like things change, but when I replace it, it doesn't. Example as follows:

```
net = <my defined model, from another function>

optimizer_1 = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.1)
optimizer_2 = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for data in training_data: # these are the batches
        <get output here>
        loss1 = <compute loss function>
        optimizer_1.zero_grad()
        loss1.backward()
        optimizer_1.step()

    loss2 = <compute a different loss function here>
    optimizer_2.zero_grad() #use a second optimizer with a different learning rate
    loss.backward()
    loss.step()
```

When I do this, it seems like it doesn't actually carry through with the second optimization on the second loss function. Why is this? I want the second optimization to have a different learning rate than the first one. However, it seems like only continuing to use the first optimizer, optimizer_1, with its respective learning rate seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

First you can accumulate the `loss1` in the inner loop. 
Next, You might want to consider merging two loss functions.

`(sum(accumulated_loss1) + loss2).backward()`

This ensures both are losses are considered during training and all the gradients are propagated in the backward pass

Comment: I'm computing the loss for every batch (and the update step), but then using the activation output after going through the full batch to feed into a computation that calculates my second loss function. I thought the first loss is still being considered during training, because I'm still using it for optimization.

So do you mean that I should be doing total_loss_1 += loss, and then do the backwards pass on this?

Also, does this mean it's irrelevant to change learning rate/optimizer for the second loss?